# How to set a height of the panel equal to the content in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var contentheight = $(".ui-page").height();
$(".ui-panel").css("height",contentheight);});
```

For the Jquery Mobile, the panel is not extending the height of the content div.
I was trying to make the the code above but it doesnt fill up the height of the panel. specially if the content has a collapsible div.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS:

```
.ui-panel .ui-panel-inner {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;  
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/GSSD3/1/)**

Comment: but if you make the page longer the slide menu scrolls too. thank you very much btw, sorry for this very late post. im not really active in SE

Comment: @raymaru, you could use the panel widget beforeopen and close events to disable/re-enable scrolling on the main content while the panel is open: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeopen